# Does the Cauchy-Schwarz integral inequality still hold for convergent improper integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, integral-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

A few hours ago I posted this solution : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3579886/629594 It seems to be all right at a first glance, given that I actually obtain the same constant as the other user, but I have just realised something : my first integral$\left(\int_0^1 \left(\frac{ax^2+bx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^2dx\right)$ is actually **improper**.
In my case, it is true that by sheer luck I actually obtain the same inequality after setting $a+b=0$ (because I may just cancel the $1+x$ after all), but is this really correct? I only know the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for Riemann integrals, but does it also hold for (convergent) improper integrals?

Comment: If the integrals are absolutely convergent improper integrals, C-S will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both $\int_a^b f^2(x)\, dx$ and $\int_a^b g^2(x)\, dx$ exist as (finite) improper Riemann integrals then for every (sufficiently small) $\delta > 0$, $\epsilon > 0$
$$
 \int_{a+\delta}^{b-\epsilon} |f(x) g(x)| \, dx \le \left(  \int_{a+\delta}^{b-\epsilon} f(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2}\left(  \int_{a+\delta}^{b-\epsilon} g(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2} \\
 \le \left(  \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2}\left(  \int_{a}^{b} g(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2} \, .
$$
The left-hand side is decreasing in both $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ and bounded, so that the limits for $\delta \to 0^+$ and $\epsilon\to 0^+$ exist. It follows that $\int_a^b |f(x) g(x)| \, dx$ exists as an improper Riemann integral, and 
$$
\int_{a}^{b} |f(x) g(x)| \, dx \le \left(  \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2}\left(  \int_{a}^{b} g(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2} \, .
$$
This implies that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) g(x) \, dx$ exists as an improper Riemann integral, compare [Proof verification: existence of improper integral, given that the integral of the absolute value is finite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2542917/42969). Since $f(x) g(x) \le |f(x)g(x)|$ we can conclude that
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) g(x) \, dx \le \left(  \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2}\left(  \int_{a}^{b} g(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2} \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you very much ! So, just to make sure since I am not really experienced with improper integrals, we just need the improper integrals to exist, it doesn't matter whther they are finite or infinite, right?

Comment: @Alexdanut: If the right-hand side is infinite then $\int_{a}^{b} |f(x) g(x)| \, dx \le \left(  \int_{a}^{b} f(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2}\left(  \int_{a}^{b} g(x)^2 \, dx\right)^{1/2}$ trivially holds. But in that case we can say nothing about the *existence* of $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) g(x) \, dx$.